# xcode app crashing on launch with breakpoint

Tags: xcode

At build and run (in simulator and on my iPhone) im now getting the following from xcode and the app never launches... however if i stop the build in xcode and then open the app it seems fine?

UPDATE:  Yes the breakpoint of course was causing the app to pause (i had forgot to remove it before posting)

The issue is with importing and using a custom font.  If i remove the imported TTF and where i added its reference in my plist things are fine. At least I now know its the font thats the issue

[image]

Comment: Delete the breakpoint you added on that line.

Comment: I'm going to assume you have no idea what a break point is ?

Comment: Your original question with just the image shows no errors and just a breakpoint. Next time I would recommend adding an error message or reading the crashlog to help determine the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

[image: removing a breakpoint]

Then run it again...

Comment: What did you use to create the gif?